# Differentiate a real license plate from printed license plate Python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a license plate recognition in python, and i want to know if somebody have some idea of how can i differentiate a real license plate from a printed in paper license plate. I cant figure it out how to do this. Any idea would help me! Thanks!

Comment: Reflection/albedo?  Paper won't reflect light int he same way a metal plate would. Movement?  Depending on how it's anchored paper may move in a breeze.  If you can see the edges of the plate, then it's probably real. I would expect it to be very hard to make a piece of paper look like a stamped piece of metal if you can see the edges. Look for defects, rips/tears or water damage.  Bleeding in the letters. Maybe even look for shadows cast by the raised surfaces of the plate, which printing won't have.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What kind of setting? What sort of constraints (and I don't mean language or libraries to use, that's jumping a bit too far ahead)? As it stands, this is way too broad and underspecified.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answers! I like your ideas Patrick, i will try with the reflection, is a very good idea. And this program is for a parking lot of a company, so the security is important and i am a little concerned about the recognition of fakes license plate. So the camera will be still and the pictures will be from the front of the cars all the times at the same distance. I am using KNN for the characters recognition. I was also thinking about analyze the texture of the image. I hope you understand me, my english is not that good.. :P